# API URL Help needed

Tags: javascript, string, api, url

I'm looking for some help and wasn't sure where to go for it. Was hoping someone more knowledgeable could give me some quick help. I'm trying to use an Api to get Hearthstone card game data and I have the end point which is
"https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards"
2:28 pm
And I have my API key which is "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" And I can't figure out how to string it all together into a single URL that will return data.
I've been trying things along the lines of "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards?x-mashape-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
But nothing's giving, any ideas if anyone has some free time?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `x-mashape-key` in your request headers rather than in the query string, according to their API take a look at the CURL request:

https://market.mashape.com/omgvamp/hearthstone

Try going here: http://requestmaker.com/ filling in the URL leaving out the last part of `x-mashape-key` and add a request header with key/value of `x-mashape-key`:`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` then hit request and you should get a response.